# stuck on last screen when shutdown ubuntu 16.10 after changing to single boot

Tags: shutdown

i'm new in Ubuntu especially Linux and i have a problem when changing my laptop(Acer aspire 4750) to single boot from dual boot(windows and ubuntu). When I turn off my laptop using the GUI or Terminal `sudo shutdown -h now`, The laptop keep stuck at the last screen when shutting down. Sometimes the dot (below the Ubuntu) hit the fourth or third row. And in couple days i'm searching on the internet, and i got nothing. I'm installing Ubuntu using single boot and format all the hardisk and it make the partition itself (i don't know if it's neccecary). Last thing that i'm doing is upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10

actually i have two problems:
- the shutdown issue
- wifi and bluetooth can't on at the same time

When i'm using dual boot there's no problem but now i'm confused. Sorry for my bad english and i don't know what i have to attach, so i will be so much appreciate your help.

Thanks